# Is it possible to detect if a RecyclerView item reached the top of the screen?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to detect when a RecyclerView item hits the top end of the screen to make changes to other views. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a scroll listener to your recyclerview object.

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                    if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
                        //top end reached
                    }
            }
        });
```

Here, `-1` means scrolling from bottom to top. Similarly, `1` means scrolling from top to bottom.

Same conventions apply for Horizontal RecyclerView. Just use `canScrollHorizontally()` instead of `canScrollVertically()`

Answer (score 0):

if you have your item's position, you can use this

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        val top = recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position)?.itemView?.top
        if(top == 0) { 
            //item reached top end 
        }
    }
})
```

be careful **findViewHolderForAdapterPosition** will return **null** when the viewHolder is recycled and no longer visible